# Trying to pass a Component through onclick in button, which clearly is the wrong method, Do not know how to incorporate State for the component dsplay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the "show button" to render the Countryinfo component in the given code but I know what I am doing is doing wrong and maybe I need to add state to the list but i am really struggling as to how?

The search function is to work as follows:

1. The fetched database is filtered acc. to input value and,
2. If the matches turn out >10 then no list is rendered and,
3. if the matches turn out between 2-10 then the list of matching countries with a show button is presented, which is supposed to display the countryinfo of that country [THE BUTTON DOESNT WORK ]
4. when the input value only matches one country then the countryinfo component is rendered

codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/country-db-issue-forked-kzkyr?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

/*
const divMagnify={
  transform: 'scale(4)'

};
*/

const Countryinfo = (props) => {
  console.log('name', props.cty[0].name.common);
  console.log('lang', props.cty[0].languages);
  console.log('flag', props.cty[0].flag);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.cty[0].name.official}</h1>
      <h4>aka {props.cty[0].name.common} </h4>

      <p>Capital: {props.cty[0].capital}</p>

      <p>Population: {props.cty[0].population}</p>

      <h2>Languages</h2>

      <ul>
        {Object.entries(props.cty[0].languages).map(([key, value], index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{value}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
      <h3>Flag</h3>

      <div>{props.cty[0].flag}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Displaycountry = (props) => {
  console.log('length', props.name.length);
  let len = props.name.length;

  if (len > 10) {
    console.log('too many');
    return <div>Too many matches, specify another filter</div>;
  } else if (len === 1) {
    return <Countryinfo cty={props.name} />;
  } else if (1 < len && len <= 10) {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.name.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {item.name.common}
              &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <button onClick={() => <Countryinfo cty={item} />}>Show</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

function App() {
  const [countrydb, setCountrydb] = useState([]);
  const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then((response) => {
      setCountrydb(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleCountrySearch = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setCountryName(
      countrydb.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.common
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <h3>Search Country Database</h3>

        <input onChange={handleCountrySearch} />
      </section>

      <section>
        <Displaycountry name={countryName} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

[image: Display for more 10 countries matching]
[image: display for less than 10 countries matching with an option to display their information(the issue)]

[image: the view when only country matches search parameter]

Comment: Maybe it's because you trying to return component from button's `onClick` method,? You can change some flag in onClick method, on the basis of which the component `Countryinfo` will be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this https://codesandbox.io/s/country-db-issue-forked-nvq2y

I've changed the return of `Displaycountry` and saved to state index of the clicked country to show its info. Also, I've changed the `Countryinfo` component, so it can display the value of one single country (not an array)

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I have been trying to get my head around on how to make it work, I am new to react so learning the ropes. thank you for taking the time out to help me!